# why does it inject "/product/image-name/" before image source

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

why does it inject "/product/image-name/" before image source

product.html:

```
<div class="product-gallery product-gallery-vertical">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <figure class="product-main-image">
                                        <img id="product-zoom" src="{{product.image1.url}}"  data-zoom-image="{{product.image1.url}}" alt="product image">
```

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = "assets/images/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ecommerce/static/assets/images/')
```

views.py:

```
def product(request, slug):
product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
print(product.image1.url)
context = {'product': product}
return render(request, "product.html", context)
```

> error:
> Not Found: /product/iphone-11/assets/images/products/Apple-iPhone-11-Black-frontimage.jpg

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("product/<slug>/", views.product, name="product"),
    path("cart/<slug>/", views.cart, name="cart"),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Seems like an issue with your URLs. Please check that or put some more reference here.

Comment: you can see the resource address that is being referenced in your code with inspect. be sure the address is valid and exists

Comment: i edited my question please check it